# A way to transfer IRC chatter/pm to gtalk

Tags: bots, irc, google-talk

I'd like to know if some sort of bot/tool/service exists that would allow people on (regular) IRC chat to me on gtalk

so: irc user X sends a pm to MyBot (f.e.); that pm forwards to me

a irc room to chat would also work fine (so everything said in channel #abc gets into my gtalk conversation with mybot@domain.com

hope I was clear enough for you to understand what I'm looking for and that anyone knows a way for me to solve it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [PircBotX](http://code.google.com/p/pircbotx/) to create an IRC bot in Java yourself, and use pm events to send gtalk messages using any old Jabber library. A quick search finds me [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp).

I did something similar once, but I made two instances of PircBotX, one to connect to the IRC server, and another to connect to this special IRC server somewhere that was configured to automatically pass on messages to popular IM protocols. I can't seem to remember what that service was called, perhaps you'll have better luck.

Comment: Bitlbee maybe?

might look into this, however it would've been easier if a solution already existed; I have a very busy schedule atm.

still Thanks though ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's the [hans-irc-gtalk bot](http://code.google.com/p/hans-irc-gtalk/) which does something like that. People need to subscribe to the messages in order to get them from gtalk. Not sure how well supported the project is.

Comment: I've found that one, however there seems to be no download available... "This project currently has no downloads."

Comment: update: found it on the source tab (stupid for me not to look there) will check it out once I have the time, Thanks.

Comment: @JLSJonas Yeah, you need to grab it from SVN and build it.